# Python procedure for changing an object

Tags: python

Like an example

```
def inc(a):
    a += 1
```

If I want to have an increment function instead or writing `var += 1` (Is not the only case, just as example) what I should do?
I know that I can `return a + 1` but I want `void` fucntion. 
Is there any ways in python?

Comment: Are you asking for an in place increment function?

Comment: @PaulRooney yes. With no OOP.

Comment: FWIW, there are no `void` functions in Python. If you don't provide an explicit return value (i.e., the function exits without a `return` statement, or it uses `return` without a value) the function will return `None`.

Comment: @PM2Ring thanks. I know that but I was thinking about another langs while asking, sorry.

Comment: I think what you want is to pass the variable as a reference. check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Comment: @realhu that doesn't work with `immutable types` like `int` so I don't think that would help here. But yes that is exactly what @Aero is trying to do.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, It is true we can't do it with int, but we can create a class and overwrite the magic class. Please check my answer:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Python data model doesn't really have variables like other languages. It has objects which may be bound to names. So a Python "variable" isn't a memory location like it is in many other languages, it's simply a label on an object. An object may have multiple names, or it may have none. See [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder for further information on this topic.

Python integers are immutable objects, so you can't actually increment them. Of course, you can create a new integer object that has a value 1 greater than the object currently named `a` and bind the name `a` to that new object.

So what you're asking to do isn't exactly a natural operation in Python. However, you can get close. As others have mentioned, you can sort-of do it by placing `a` into a mutable container object. Eg,

```
def inc(lst):
    lst[0] += 1

a = 7
b = [a]
inc(b)
print b, a
```

**output**

```
[8] 7
```

A somewhat more satisfactory approach is to refer to the name via the `global()` dictionary:

```
def inc(k):
    globals()[k] += 1 

a = 7
inc('a')
print a
```

**output**

```
8
```

However, modifying things via `globals()` is generally frowned upon, and it's useless if you want to modify a name that's local to a function.

---

Another option is to define a custom class:

```
class MutInt(object):
    def __init__(self, v):
        self.v = v

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.v)

    def inc(self):
        self.v += 1

a = MutInt(7)
print a
a.inc()
print a
```

**output**

```
7
8
```

But that's still rather ugly (IMHO), and you'd have to define all the methods of `int` in it to make the class useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by making `a` global

```
def add_one():
    global a
    a += 1
```

Notice you don't have to pass `a` into the function. I would highly recommend against doing this, however.

Comment: That works for ``a`` variable only, but I need one method for each.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not possible

Comment: It is not possible in python using global variables, if your variables were stored as attributes of an object or in a `dict` then you might be able to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `global` statement to modify a `global` variable in python:

```
def inc(amount=1):
    global a
    a+=amount

a = 1
inc(2)
print(a)
```

this will allow the function to override the value of the globally defined variable.

Comment: That actually gives me ``SyntaxError: name 'a' is parameter and global``

Comment: Change the function from `inc(a)` to `inc()` and it will work as in my answer

Answer (score 0):

We can't pass immutable type like `int` as a variable as a reference:[How do I pass a variable by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference). But we can create a new class and overwrite this one's **self add** operation with python's **magic class** `__iadd__`.

```
class CInt(object):

    x = 0

    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __add__(self, y):
        return CInt(self.x + y)

    def __iadd__(self, y):
        self.x = self.x + y


def inc(a):
    a += 1


a = CInt(2)

print(a.x)

inc(a)

print(a.x)
```

The result would be:

```
2
3
```